# How to remove error : Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case '^' (0x5E):') to another?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 case'(':
       Globals.operatorStack.Push(a[i]);
       break;
 case'^':
       if (operatorStack.Count == 0)
       {
        Globals.operatorStack.Push(a[i]);
        }
```

The error occurs on case'^':
How to remove this error?
Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 1):

C# does not allow implicit fall-through for case labels, you need to explicitly fall-through using the syntax `goto case [value]`. If you did not intend to go to another case label, add a `break` statement at the end of the `case`.

Other remark: I'm not sure if a global operator stack is a good idea, although I know nothing about your use case except that it looks like a parser. Can you not use an instance or local variable?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break;` after the closing `}` of the if-statement.